# What is the maximum database size of mongodb 3.0.3 with WiredTiger engine

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

What is the maximum database size of WiredTiger engine?
There is only the maximum database size of MMAPv1 on MongoDB Manual as below.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: 64 bits equals what again? Per node that is

Comment: Is _+∞_ really the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

WiredTiger has no upper limit when sharded. It does not use mmap. It uses normal block I/O. To achieve high performance, it uses a bag of tricks like Log Structured Merge Tree, lock free algorithms, fine grained locks and many more
Ref:-
http://source.wiredtiger.com/1.4.2/architecture.html
http://www.slideshare.net/wiredtiger/mongo-db-worldwiredtiger